# Auto reloading of inline plugin does not working in grails 3.3.9

Tags: grails

Whenever we apply any changes in the main app Classes the changes are reflected but if any code changes are made in the inline plugin we need to re-run the application . 
So, Is there any solution of compiling or reloading the inline plugin in grails 3.3.9?

The gradle.properties of my inline plugin is

```
grailsVersion=3.3.9
gormVersion=6.1.11
gradleWrapperVersion=3.5
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps outlined in the documentation? http://docs.grails.org/3.3.x/guide/plugins.html - > installing local plugins -> Configure the plugin to enable reloading ?

Comment: Yeah i added the exploded=true in my plugins gradle.properties but it didn't work.

Comment: @erichelgeson Currently i am adding my inline plugin in the dependencies portion of build.gradle. So i removed it and added as follows grails{
    plugins{
        compile project(':myplugin')
    }
} in build.gradle of the application. But i am facing error like  "Could not find method grails() for arguments [build_dpq16rrgnx4ot3z83xmk9i056$_run_closure1@38785820] on root project 'repo_test' of type org.gradle.api.Project." . Could you please provide where i am wrong on this

Comment: Do you have a  buildscript level dependency (not an application level dependency) on the `grails-gradle-plugin` Gradle plugin?  That would be near the top of `build.gradle` in the `buildscript { ... }` block.  That is what handles the `grails` method call mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yeah it worked.Thanks everyone